# How to make sense of a PCB in electrical circuit terms,

Tags: pcb

How can I 'read' a PCB? An electrical circuit schematic is one thing, but this is a whole nother ballgame to me. Are there any standard ways to go about things when deciphering a printed circuit board in terms of the electrical circuit layout of the electronic components soldered to it? How is this normally done?

Comment: Such a question is really too broad to meet this site's requirement of *specific answerability*.  There are a laundry list of techniques, like combining good pictures of each side, but questions that can only have a list of ideas as an answer do not fit the site's mission.

Comment: Well, i obviously ran a google search first but couldn't find anything. If you have any good resources, that would be fantastic, obviating the need for thjis question, or else some tips on how to make the question specific enough to meet this site's requirements while keeping its essence

Comment: The tip is, you gotta grunt through it.   The circuit understanding comes from reading the schematic.   The PCB is just the physical realization of the schematic.   Basically you start with some component you can identify, cross reference the scheme, and procede component by component.  There is no guarantee, and actually highly unlikely, that the layout on the scheme matches the PCB.   Components can be anywhere.  Electricity doesn't care.  Often times the board will have traces you can't even see,  which will confound your efforts.   Basically its a huge time suck.

Comment: The issue you're likely dealing with us trying to comprehend what the circuit does or is based on the PCB.   That's very difficult to impossible to do and requires considerable experience.  When confronted with an unknown PCB, the engineers first step is to draw it out as a schematic.   You'll drive yourself nutty trying to understand it right from the PCB

Comment: It's like this: Imagine the schematic diagram with stretchable, unbreakable wiring. Run it through the blender a couple of times. Then hammer it flat on your static-proof cutting board. There you go: a PCB ready for production and examination.

Comment: Thanks. That about answers my question : you can't, for all intents and purposes, understand a PCB without having access to the schematics itself, or if you can, it's far too time consuming to make it worth it, generally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Reading" a PCB is a learned skill that can really only be acquired by doing. Nobody can really tell you *how* to reverse-engineer it, you have to learn that on your own. Usually the best way to learn it is to design PCBs for yourself and understand why components are laid out in a certain way and how they are routed to each other. It is often a long-drawn out process for anything but the simplest of boards.

I recently reverse-engineered a LAN/VGA module created by Keysight to connect their 3000X series scopes to an external VGA monitor. I documented the process here:

https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/dsfauxlan-reverse-engineering-the-agilentkeysight-dsoxlan-lanvga-modul-220158/msg2805820/#msg2805820

Parts of it I was able to determine by inspection, but other parts I had to brute-force. I had to probe out many of the component pins and vias manually using the continuity test on my multimeter in order to figure out where they were connected. If I didn't do PCB layout for a living, I'm not really sure how I would have done this. Having an understanding of how PCBs are designed, manufactured, and assembled was absolutely crucial.

Comment: "spent a few hours every day for the next several weeks probing every pin and every pad on the board, noting where they were connected" ---- time-consuming indeed lol

Comment: Yes indeed, it was no small task!